# have very recent packages in CentOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, package-management, yum

Normally versions of packages available in CenOS and Ubunti repositories differ, Ubuntu tends to have the latest-greatest versions, while CentOS is more conservative. Is it possible to add some repos in CentOS with more recent versions then in the CentOS official repos?

Comment: Have you looked into EPEL and RPMForge?

Comment: @DopeGhoti EPEL doesn't offer newer versions, just extra packages (hence the name "**E**xtra **P**ackages for **E**nterprise **L**inux"). `IUS` offers newer co-installable packages.

Comment: Which newer packages do you require?

Comment: @jordanm, I'm trying to have tar updated, currently it is tar-1.23-13.el6.x86_64, however Yocto environment requires it to be newer. I checked through various CentOS related repos listed at https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories  but none of them have newer tar package. So I ended up building it from sources.